# iTextPdf Replacing PDF objects wrong signs

Tags: c#, replace, stream, itext, itext7

I used this Example in C#

https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/replacing-pdf-objects

The Problem in my Code:

```
String replacedData = IO.Util.JavaUtil.GetStringForBytes(data).Replace(placeholder, replacetext);
```

The String `replacetext` is: 34,60

In the Final PDF

[image: finalpdf-wrong-replace-screenshot]

What can i do, any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually that example should have a mile-high warning sign. It only works under very benign circumstances, and depending on your search and replacement texts you can easily damage the content stream contents.

In your case the circumstances are not benign: It looks like the font in question is only subset-embedded, i.e. only the glyphs used in the original PDF are embedded. Apparently the comma glyph is not used originally, so it is not included in the embedded subset and cannot be displayed; instead that framed question mark is shown. (It could also be a case of a not quite standard encoded font.)

Additionally the widths of the excluded glyphs appears to be set to 0, causing the '6' to be drawn over the replacement glyph for the comma.

Comment: Apparently the comma glyph is not used originally, so it is not included in the embedded subset and cannot be displayed; instead that framed question mark is shown.  

This was the Problem. We generate the PDF also before we replace the Placeholder. We changed the Settings in Acrobat and now it Works.